# Strange use of verb "ser"

Tags: gramática

> Aquel hombre era Hari Seldon, **el ser que** representaba la única chispa de esfuerzo creador que subsistía en la decadencia general.
> *Fundación e Imperio* de Isaac Asimov

I don't understand the use of the verb *ser* in this context - what grammar is this?

Comment: "el ser" in this case refers to the noun "the being", as opposed to the verb "to be".

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/ser **ser (1)** is the *verb*, but here is also **ser (2)** a *noun* with several meanings; in this case, *the being* - as brazofuerte indicates ut supra

Comment: is it like a human bbein?

Comment: Yes. It would be like "the human being" but it also could be like "the creature". A being is something that has [the quality or state of having existence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/being)

Comment: is it like...he being the being who...)?

Answer (score 5):

As pointed by @brazofuerte and @Joseph_Jaroslav, the sentence is not using the word **ser** as a verb but as a **noun**. You can check the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/ser) and found two different meanings marked respectively with the superindexes 1 (verb) and 2 (noun).

You have also noticed a similar situation with the word **being** in English that can be a gerund or a noun as well depending on the context.

You can search the original text in English to check the translation. I've found the excerpt using Google Books

> That **man** was Hari Seldon, the **man** who represented the one spark of
> creative effort left among the gathering decay...
> *Fundation and Empire* by Isaac Asimov

The Spanish translator chose to not repeat the word **man** and instead he replaced the second one by the noun "being (EN) / ser (ES)". A bad choice, in my opinion, because it conflicts the original omitting such repetition intended by the author.